# How to call external java script function from android Webview

Tags: android, android-webview

I load a HTML page in android webview. The HTML page contains 3 Buttons Back,Continue and next.

I want to get the click events of Buttons and call the external java script files functions. Any way to capture the buttons events without implementing  the JavaScript Interface and call the JS function.

I search Stackoverflow but I was not able to get answer that can solve my issue.